# Enable ipv6 ssh traffic from ipv4 subnet on AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, ipv6

I'm trying to ssh into an ec2 instance using its ipv6 address. If I set the security group to allow ssh traffic from any ipv6 address, I can get in, but this is far too permissive. As such, the security group has an entry allowing incoming traffic from my ipv4 address, but my ssh traffic to the instance's ipv6 address gets blocked in this case. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that may read this: the issue is that when one accesses an ipv6 address, your ipv6 address is used. As such, you can google to get your ipv6 address and then copy this into the inbound rules in your security group.